# resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri (Android studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an image from the firebase db and assign it to an imagebutton to preview it but i get the fail "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri" Here my related codes:

```
var_resim2=dataSnapshot.child("user_resim").getValue().toString(); 
Uri my_resim = Uri.parse(var_resim2);
kul_resim.setImageURI(my_resim);
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: log your `var_resim2` and check if it's a valid url

Comment: Oussema Aroua yes i checked that and it is actually a valid url starting with https://  query..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `Picasso` lib is the best way :
add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

then

```
Picasso.with(this).load(var_resim2).into(kul_resim);
```

or you need to download and then set it to the `ImageView`

Comment: Omg. i just realised your answer to this and i tried what you say and Bam! It worked! But thanks to my curiosity i couldn't help my self not asking this questions;  if it is so easy why do they try to do it by the other way i mean downloading the object from the url and setting it as a drawable item and then settin it to the image button. If there is such an easy way as Ousemma Aroua adviced .

Comment: Also what else we can do with Picasso Library :) I'm so excited!